# Upload a video from Windows Phone 8 to Azure Storage

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, azure-storage

Apologies not a specific code question - but frankly stumped as to where to begin. Scrounged around for a while but doesn't seem like anyone has written up how to upload a video from a Windows Phone 8 app into Azure Storage.

Perhaps someone on here has the know how (or at least pointer to do so).

Comment: Do take a look here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-upload-data-blob-storage/. This should give an idea about uploading files to Azure Storage using Azure Mobile Service.

Comment: Guess you could give a try working with the `Media Services` on `Win Azure`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn735908.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following documentation shows how to import an image into blob storage. You should be able to upload an MP4 or any other binary file using the same methodology.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/

Comment: Got in touch with the content developer for that article. It doesn't currently work with videos - but working together to get something together similar for videos (there are differences).